# How to create a class for a SwiftUI element with closures similar to buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui

Sorry if this question is stupid. I am new to SwiftUI and I sometimes have difficult to see obvious stuff.

This is the first app that I am fully using it seriously, after 12 years programming with the old paradigm Objective C/Swift. So, I am more confused and cannot wrap my mind around some stuff.

I have this block in my main ContentView:

```
VStack {
  Button(action: {. //1
    self.language = Language.english
    changeDescription()               
  }) {
    Image("en") //2
  }
  .cornerRadius(10)
  .padding(4)
  .overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
      .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: language == Language.english ? 2 : 0) // 3
   )
   Text("US")  // 4
}
```

This blocks is used many times. Parts marked 1, 2, 3, and 4 are the only ones that change.

ContentView is polluted with many entries like this. I want to create a class I can move a lot of this code and clean the main view code.

You see the Button syntax

```
Button(action: {
  // action goes here               
}) {
  // view goes here
}
```

Buttons have these two closures, one for action and the other one for the view.

I would like to create this class that has 4 of these, something like:

```
MyClass(action: {
  // action goes here               
}) {view:
  // view goes here
} {overlay:
  // overlay content goes here
} {associatedText:
  // view goes here
}
```

something like that.

If this is not the correct way, something that can simplify the main view.

How do I create a class that has this signature?

Please give the simplest example you can, so I can understand. Pretend I am 5 years old.

If the class is hard to build, just give me the general lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a button-like `struct` called `MyButton`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyButton<Label: View>: View {  // 1
    let action: () -> Void            // 2
    let label:  () -> Label           // 2
    
    var body: some View {
        label()                       // 4
        .onTapGesture() {             // 5
            action()                  // 6
        }
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}

// Now let's use MyButton in an example
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyButton(action: {
                self.count += 1
            }) {
                Text("Press Me")
            }
            Text("count = \(count)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanantion**

1. `struct MyButton` is a *generic* `struct` that is a `View` and has a `Label` which is a `View`.  Making it *generic* allows us to avoid explicitly specifying what type the `label` closure returns.  The compiler will fill it in for us.
2. `MyButton` takes a closure called `action` that takes no inputs and returns `Void`.
3. `MyButton` takes a closure called `label` which produces a `Label` (which is a `View`) when called.
4. Call `label()` to produce the `Label` `View`.
5. Use an `.onTapGesture` to simulate the button press.
6. When tapped, call the `action()` closure.

---

### Trailing-closure Syntax

The above example uses [*trailing-closure syntax*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) to omit the argument label `label:` and write the last closure outside of the initializer for `MyButton`.  Here is the other way to write it:

```
MyButton(action: {
    self.count += 1
}, label: {
    Text("Press Me")
})
```

Comment: whoooooooooooaaaaaaa! Much more complex that I thought. I have to digest that. Two questions: (1) at the part you implement `Text("Press Me)`... how can that closure have no parameter and the one previous to that has the `action:`? The second question I will type later to not make a confusion.

Comment: We could have written it with the `label:`.  This is using a feature of Swift called *trailing closure syntax* where you can put the last closure after the function and omit the label.

Comment: brilliant. I still have to digest that but I think I more or less understand.

Answer (score 1):

For such purpose there is `ButtonStyle` pattern in SwiftUI, so you define your style as like

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    let text: String

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            configuration.label
              .cornerRadius(10)
              .padding(4)
              .overlay(
                 RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: lineWidth)
                )
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

and apply it where needed (having for free all button behaviour)

```
Button(action: {
    self.language = Language.english
    changeDescription()
}) {
    Image("en")
}
.buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(lineWidth: language == Language.english ? 2 : 0, text: "US"))
```